# Postgres: update column type and parse column value from json to float

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

**Example Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
    example_column TEXT,
)
```

**Example Record (json stored as text):**

```
INSERT INTO example_table VALUES ('{"value": "1.3", "Type": "float"}')
```

Goal is to:

1. Update column type to Double Precision
2. Update the value to be 1.3

I know the following is close to what I want, but I can't find the correct syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE example_table ALTER COLUMN example_column DOUBLE PRECISION...missing parse syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a `using` clause to define the conversion:

```
alter table example_table
   alter example_column 
      type double precision using (example_column::jsonb ->> 'value')::double precision
```